# contour integration problem..

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

how can we find $$\int_C e^{2z} 9^{z-2} dz,$$
 where $C$ is the the contour from $z = 0$ to $z = 1 − i$

Comment: edited what i could, end of last sentence nonsensical to me. which path should be taken on $C$ from $0$ to $1-i$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$e^{2z}9^{2-z}=81e^{2(1-\log 3)z}$$

and $e^z$ is analyic.  So, the integral is path independent.

Comment: Good Point there!

Comment: @amcalde Thank you!  Much appreciative.